# Creating a new variable by conditional recoding based on multiple variables in R

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements, recode

I have a longitudinal dataset that contains information for up to 59 jobs for every respondent. I am interested in the questions:

```
REASON LEFT JOB IF NOT CURRENTLY WORKING JOB 01 2012
REASON LEFT JOB IF NOT CURRENTLY WORKING JOB 02 2012
.
.
.
```

Each has 25 different choices, of which I am only interested in the first three (1-Layoff, 2-Company closed, 3-End of temp work). I want to recode these 59 variables into 1 variable, so if somebody lost their job due to either company closure or layoff (regardless of the number of the job, I want to code it as 0, and if due to end of temp work I want to recode it as 1.)
I can write:

```
Jobloss[Job1==1|Job1==2|Job2==1|Job2==2]<-0
Jobloss[Job1==3|Job2==3]<-1
```

It would be easy if I had only 2 variables for job loss; but I have 59. 
Is there a short way to tell R to code the new variable as 0, if any of these variables/columns (c(1:59))==1 or ==2.

I need to use it not only for job loss but for some other questions, too; so this command could save lots of hours for me. I would really appreciate if you could help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use apply on the rows to check if any of the columns are less than 3. See the code below for an example.

```
df <- data.frame(Job1 = sample(1:3, 100, TRUE), 
                 Job2 = sample(1:3, 100, TRUE),
                 Job3 = sample(1:3, 100, TRUE))
df$Jobloss <- as.numeric(apply(df, 1, function(z) any(z < 3)))

df
```

Answer (score -1):

You can write a function that does the calculations you ask for, create a new data frame by applying that function across the columns of your data frame, and then measure which rows have a column greater than 0. Below, `my_df` should be a data frame that contains only the 59 variables about individuals' jobs. You could also subset it to those variables in the line with the apply function.

```
my_function <- function(my_var)
{
    my_output <- rep(NA, length(my_var))
    my_output[my_var == 1 | my_var == 2] <- 0
    my_output[my_var == 3] <- 1
    return(my_output)
}
new_df <- apply(my_df, 2, my_function)
my_df$Jobloss <- as.integer(rowSums(new_df, na.rm = TRUE) > 0)
```

I assumed you want anything other than a 1, 2, or 3 to be marked as NA. If that is not the case then you would have to adjust the first line in the function.

Comment: Oh actually sorry, this creates 0's, not NA's for anything other than my_var==3. I want NA's for everything else, instead. There already are NA's in the data and there are other answer choices for example 4, 5 etc. I want NA's for anything other than 1, 2 or 3.